# Can Java have text in the background of a graphics file?

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics

I have this code and its supposed to have the text "Simple Animation" scroll across the screen in swirling colors. Right now, it does that, but even after the text moves along, the color still stays. I was wondering if there was a way to have text in the background. For example, I was thinking I could just print out the exact same "Simple Animation" but in the same color as the background and about 10 pixels behind the actual text. However, when I tried this, the white text (that's the background color) just covered the swirling colors. I tried googling if I could have background text, but from I read, the only thing that a background can do is set the color. So, is there a way to have text in the background in a Java Graphics file?

Here is my Code:

```
       import java.awt.Graphics;
       import java.awt.Color;
       import java.awt.Font;
       import javax.swing.*;

public class Scrolling_Sign extends JApplet implements Runnable {
 String mesag = "Simple Animation";
  Font f = new Font("Bauhaus 93",Font.BOLD,72);
  Color colors[] = new Color[100000];
  Thread runThread;
    int Xposition = 600;      

  public void init()  {    
     setBackground(Color.white);
  }

  public void start() {
     if (runThread == null) {
        runThread = new Thread(this);
        runThread.start();
    }
  }
  public void stop() {
     if (runThread != null) {
        runThread.stop();
        runThread = null;
     }

  }

  public void run() {   
     float c = 0;      

     for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        colors[i] = Color.getHSBColor(c, (float)1.0,(float)1.0);            

        c += .02;   

     }



     int i = 0;
     while (true) {
        setForeground(colors[i]);

        repaint();
        i++;

        try { Thread.sleep(100); }
           catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        if (i == colors.length ) i = 0;
     }

  }
  public void paint(Graphics g) {

     g.setFont(f);
        g.drawString(mesag,Xposition,100);
     Xposition--;
     if (Xposition < -290)  {

        Xposition = 600;

     }

  }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please read [Why is Thread.stop deprecated?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Comment: You sould also have a read of [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) and [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I am currently taking Computer Science in school, and my teacher wants all the graphics to appear in the Applets. So, there is nothing I can do about that.

Comment: *"..there is nothing I can do about that."* That's incorrect & defeatist. At the very least you should refer the teacher to the linked article. If they persist with demanding applets, ask them to show you how to deploy an 'hello world' applet on the net via the university site. That should dampen their enthusiasm for applets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. Never draw directly within a JApplet or other top-level window.
2. Instead draw in the paintComponent of a JPanel that is displayed within the applet. The Swing tutorials will show you how.
3. Be sure to call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method within your override, and again read the [Swing tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) to see why. For more tutorials see: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)
4. This is Swing -- use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to drive your animation, not threads.
5. If you ever do use Threads, **never** call `Thread#stop()` or use any other deprecated methods. Please read [Why is Thread.stop deprecated?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).
6. Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9986368/522444) for an example of Swing animation using a Swing Timer.
7. Unless this is for a class assignment, don't create JApplets as this is a dead technology, something even Oracle will tell you.
8. To display text in the background use the java.awt.Graphics method for writing text: `drawString(...)`. Either that or place a JLabel over your background image.